# Rebuilding a widget in another screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem.
I do not understand why my widgets are rebuilding my screen when it is not active.

My screens path looks like this:
chooseTrail->fillProfile->passEmail.
When I go to the screen "passEmail", screen widgets "chooseTrail" are starting to rebuild.

This is what mine looks like routeGenerator:

```
case '/chooseTrail':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: RouteSettings(name: '/chooseTrail'),
          builder: (BuildContext context) => ChooseTrailPage.allTrails(),
        );

        return _errorRoute();
      case '/fillProfile':
        if (settings.arguments is String) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: RouteSettings(name: '/fillProfile'),
            builder: (BuildContext context) => FillProfilePage(
              settings.arguments,
            ),
          );
        }

        return _errorRoute();
      case '/passEmail':
        if (settings.arguments is String) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: RouteSettings(name: '/passEmail'),
            builder: (BuildContext context) => PassEmailPage(
              settings.arguments,
            ),
          );
        }

        return _errorRoute();
```

This is how I switch screens:

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/chooseTrail');
```

And this is what a "chooseTrail" screen fragment looks like :

```
class ChooseTrailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final KayakRenterModel _kayakRenterModel;
  final bool _allTrails;

  ChooseTrailPage(this._kayakRenterModel) : this._allTrails = false;

  ChooseTrailPage.allTrails()
      : this._kayakRenterModel = null,
        this._allTrails = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: TrailProviderModel(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: ChooseRiverProviderModel(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MainWidget(_kayakRenterModel, _allTrails),
    );
  }
}

class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final KayakRenterModel _kayakRenterModel;
  final bool _allTrails;

  MainWidget(this._kayakRenterModel, this._allTrails);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TrailProviderModel _trailProviderModel =
        Provider.of<TrailProviderModel>(context, listen: true);

    ChooseRiverProviderModel _chooseRiverProviderModel =
        Provider.of<ChooseRiverProviderModel>(context, listen: false);

    void _getTrails() async {
      try {
        String link;

        if (_allTrails) {
          link = getApiLink('uu');
        } else {
          link = getApiLink(
              'uu');
        }

        final response = await getData(link);

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          _trailProviderModel.trails = trailsFromJson(response.data);

          _chooseRiverProviderModel.rivers
              .add(RiverModel(id: -1, name: 'Wszystkie'));

          List<RiverModel> rivers =
              Set.of(_trailProviderModel.trails.map((e) => e.river)).toList();

          for (RiverModel item in rivers) {
            if (_chooseRiverProviderModel.rivers
                    .where((element) => element.id == item.id)
                    .length ==
                0) {
              _chooseRiverProviderModel.rivers.add(item);
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      } finally {
        _trailProviderModel.isLoaded = true;
      }
    }

    if (!_trailProviderModel.isLoaded) {
      _getTrails();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildMyAppBar('uu'),
      body: SafeArea(.....
```

Rebuilding already starts on Scaffold.
I am asking for any help, because I really don't know how to solve this problem.
I will add that the flutter version is 1.22.5

Comment: you have to be prepared that widgets could be built at any time - this is not a "problem", this is a "feature" - more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html)

Comment: I understand, but in screen 3 I am not calling rebuild widgets from screen 1 and it does